# Getting a DoMul error in gamemaker

Tags: game-maker

Basically what I am trying to do is multiply a number the user enters by a random number generated between 1 and 9. Then I want to display a message stating the random number(lucky number) that they got and the total points they received from it (user input * random number). Every time I do this I get an error DoMul. Am I missing something from my multiplication equation? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
//inputs: Get number of points from user
var points, luckNum, ranNum, total;
points = get_string("Please enter the amount of points: ",1);

//processing: generate a random number(1-9)
ranNum = random(9);

//multply lucky number and the points entered
total = points*ranNum;


//output: a message to user stating lucky number and the total points to be 
added                 
message = "Your lucky number is: ." + string(ranNum)+ "The total points to  
be added is: ." + string(total);     
show_message(message);


//updated score

}
```

Comment: I don't know GameMaker, but are you sure you're not accidentally multiplying a string and a number? Is the data type of `points` a number, or a string?

Comment: That's what it was. Thanks for the help